# Using an ActiveX DLL in Visual Studio 2022 causes System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: vb.net, vb6, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build a VB.NET Windows Forms application in VS 2022 using an ActiveX DLL named CP4DLL that I built many years ago in VB6.

I have included a reference to the DLL in the project and the code recognises the objects, methods and properties from the DLL but when I run the VB.NET code it generates the following message:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Creating an instance of
> the COM component with CLSID {`59CA4977-912A-47C6-BAB7-D1B26C0D6ACC`}
> from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: `800a0beb`
> `0x800A0BEB`.'"

I have a VB6 .EXE application which uses that DLL and when I install it on my computer it and it runs fine.

What else do I need to add to the VB.NET project to solve this problem ?

Comment: That appears to be a DAO error "E_DAO_FileAccessDenied" - are you using DAO?

Comment: If you look in the typelib of the VB6 DLL (using OLEView) you will be able to see if that GUID `59CA4977-912A-47C6-BAB7-D1B26C0D6ACC` is present in that DLL. If not, the problem is somewhere else, maybe a dependency.  I google searched that GUID however and it didn't turn up anything else which may indicate it is inside that DLL (or at least not very commonly used).  The problem could still lie in a dependency however.

Comment: Make sure you are building for 32 bit

Comment: The DLL does use DAO to communicate with an Access database.

Comment: I have referenced DAO 3.6 Type Library in the VB.NET project.
I have not used OLEView before but I have now run it on the DLL and I am not sure where I will find the required information on the DLL's dependencies - can you suggest a link.